# Mark question as a bug or enhancement to the framework it deal with - Enhancement to Stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request

**99%** of the times SO question deals with question that their cause is due to not knowing how to use something or not using it correctly.
However in **1%** of the cases, the problem is in the framework that has a bug or simply not flexible enough (and 1% of milions of questions are a lot). In these cases the answer can sometime provide a workaround to this situation *but* it is not the most valuable answer that SO could provide.

If there was a way to mark those question in a special tag of **Bug-Fix-required**. or **Enhancement-required** (not a common tag) that could be upvote of how many developers requires it. By that we could improve the feedback and communication between framework developers and framework users.

And by framework I mean any developing language, and frameworks like (Android, MySQL, REST, .NET, etc.)

Comment: So you want SO to become a bug tracker for all external projects? No thanks. The correct approach would of course be to open a bug at the tracker of the specific library/framework/etc, and then link to that bug when asking for a workaround on SO.

Comment: This feature is not supposed to replace the bug mechanism in each of the projects, but only to provide indication which problems are minor and which bother many users. according to the views and upvote, that's it.

Comment: @GyRo, do you mean the maintainers would look at those stats on Stack Overflow and use them to prioritize their bugs? I don't see that happening, ever.

Comment: Ok, you want SO to become an _extension_ of the bug tracker. Still just as bad - like Frédéric said I can't see that happening, it would create additional work for SO as well as the maintainers. And most bug tracking tools already have a feature like the one you describe, where people can vote for a bug or add themselves to a watch list to get updated on the bug progress; see e.g. [this example in the glassfish jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047) which has both of those features enabled.

Answer (score 11):

If the question is about a bug in a software product, a bug report should be filed with the product's bug tracker if one is available.

Stack Overflow is not a bug tracker. You may post a question to ask if something is intentional behavior or a bug, but you don't post bug reports as questions.

Stack Overflow is not a replacement for UserVoice either (although the original meta was once a UserVoice setup a very long time ago).